# How to create extension method/lamba function for this

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods

I am doing the following:

Where 'fc' is a Control with list of properties. 'nc' is where I am putting the Property value.

With the route seen below I will have to do this 10x to collect/map 10 Properties. Is there way to make this less repetitive?

```
   FormControl fc;
   FormControlProperty fp;
   NoteTemplateControl nc;
   fp = fc.Property.Find(i => i.name == "Display");
   if (fp != null)
   {
       nc.Display = fp.Value;
   }
   fp = fc.Property.Find(i => i.name == "Text");
   if (fp != null)
   {
       nc.Text = fp.Value;
   }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void Map(this Control fc, string name, Action<string> assign)
{
   var fp = fc.Property.Find(i => i.name == name);
   if (fp != null) assign(fp.Value);
}
```

usage:

```
theControl.Map("Display", v => theControl.Display = v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just write:

```
var doit = new Action<FormControlProperty, NoteTemplateControl>((fp, nc) =>
    {
        // put your code here
    });
```

Then you can call it with:

```
doit(fp1, nc1);
doit(fp2, nc2);
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Extension method.

```
public static void FindProperty(this NoteTemplateControl nc, FormControl fc, string propertyName)
{
    var fp = fc.Property.Find(i => i.name == propertyName);
    if (fp != null)
    {
        var setter = typeof(nc).GetProperty(propertyName).GetSetMethod();
        setter(nc, new object[]{ fp.Value });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a big list of properties to go through, you could use reflection in a ForEach loop. (assuming Property is `IEnumerable<>` )

```
fc.Property.ToList().ForEach(fp =>
                      {
                          var prop = nc.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
                          if (prop != null)
                            prop.SetValue(nc, fp.Value);
                      });
```